# add previous ans next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i wanna add next and previous button to my page jsp , I have actually multiple form which i can reach with a menu but i would like to pass from a form to another by clicking both  on next or previous and with the menu 
thank you for you attention and help I've seen a lot of topic but none of them could help me

```js
$(function() {
 /*
 number of fieldsets
 */
 
 var fieldsetCount = $('#formElem').children().length;
 
 /*
 current position of fieldset / navigation link
 */
 var current  = 1;
    
 /*
 sum and save the widths of each one of the fieldsets
 set the final sum as the total width of the steps element
 */
 var stepsWidth = 0;
    var widths   = new Array();
 $('#steps .step').each(function(i){
        var $step   = $(this);
  widths[i]    = stepsWidth;
        stepsWidth   += $step.width();
    });
 $('#steps').width(stepsWidth);
 
 /*
 to avoid problems in IE, focus the first input of the form
 */
 $('#formElem').children(':first').find(':input:first').focus(); 
 
 /*
 show the navigation bar
 */
 $('#navigation').show();
 
 /*
 when clicking on a navigation link 
 the form slides to the corresponding fieldset
 */
    $('#navigation a').bind('click',function(e){
  var $this = $(this);
  var prev = current;
  $this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
        $this.parent().addClass('selected');
  /*
  we store the position of the link
  in the current variable 
  */
  current = $this.parent().index() + 1;
  /*
  animate / slide to the next or to the corresponding
  fieldset. The order of the links in the navigation
  is the order of the fieldsets.
  Also, after sliding, we trigger the focus on the first 
  input element of the new fieldset
  If we clicked on the last link (confirmation), then we validate
  all the fieldsets, otherwise we validate the previous one
  before the form slided
  */
        $('#steps').stop().animate({
            marginLeft: '-' + widths[current-1] + 'px'
        },500,function(){
   if(current == fieldsetCount)
    validateSteps();
   else
    validateStep(prev);
   $('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(current) +')').find(':input:first').focus(); 
  });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
 
 /*
 clicking on the tab (on the last input of each fieldset), makes the form
 slide to the next step
 */
 $('#formElem > fieldset').each(function(){
  var $fieldset = $(this);
  $fieldset.children(':last').find(':input').keydown(function(e){
   if (e.which == 9){
    $('#navigation li:nth-child(' + (parseInt(current)+1) + ') a').click();
    /* force the blur for validation */
    $(this).blur();
    e.preventDefault();
   }
  });
 });
 
 /*
 validates errors on all the fieldsets
 records if the Form has errors in $('#formElem').data()
 */
 function validateSteps(){
  var FormErrors = false;
  for(var i = 1; i < fieldsetCount; ++i){
   var error = validateStep(i);
   if(error == -1)
    FormErrors = true;
  }
  $('#formElem').data('errors',FormErrors); 
 }
 
 /*
 validates one fieldset
 and returns -1 if errors found, or 1 if not
 */
 function validateStep(step){
  if(step == fieldsetCount) return;
  
  var error = 1;
  var hasError = false;
  $('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(step) +')').find(':input:not(button)').each(function(){
   var $this   = $(this);
   var valueLength = jQuery.trim($this.val()).length;
   
   if(valueLength == ''){
    hasError = true;
    $this.css('background-color','#FFEDEF');
   }
   else
    $this.css('background-color','#FFFFFF'); 
  });
  var $link = $('#navigation li:nth-child(' + parseInt(step) + ') a');
  $link.parent().find('.error,.checked').remove();
  
  var valclass = 'checked';
  if(hasError){
   error = -1;
   valclass = 'error';
  }
  $('<span class="'+valclass+'"></span>').insertAfter($link);
  
  return error;
 }
 
 /*
 if there are errors don't allow the user to submit
 */
 $('#registerButton').bind('click',function(){
  if($('#formElem').data('errors')){
   alert('Please correct the errors in the Form');
   return false;
  } 
 });
 
});
```

```css
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
body{
    color:#444444;
    font-size:13px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-family:"Century Gothic", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#content{
    margin:15px auto;
    text-align:center;
    width:600px;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper{
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    width:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#steps{
    width:600px;
 /*height:320px;*/
    overflow:hidden;
}
.step{
    float:left;
    width:600px;
 /*height:320px;*/
}
#navigation{
    height:45px;
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}
#navigation ul{
    list-style:none;
 float:left;
 margin-left:22px;
}
#navigation ul li{
 float:left;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
    position:relative;
 margin:0px 2px;
}
#navigation ul li a{
    display:block;
    height:45px;
    background-color:#444;
    color:#777;
    outline:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:45px;
    padding:0px 20px;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    background:
        -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0.09, rgb(240,240,240)),
        color-stop(0.55, rgb(227,227,227)),
        color-stop(0.78, rgb(240,240,240))
        );
    background:
        -moz-linear-gradient(
        center bottom,
        rgb(240,240,240) 9%,
        rgb(227,227,227) 55%,
        rgb(240,240,240) 78%
        )
}
#navigation ul li a:hover,
#navigation ul li.
ted a{
    background:#d8d8d8;
    color:#666;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
span.checked{
    background:transparent url(../img/checked.png) no-repeat top left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:1px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
span.error{
    background:transparent url(img/error.png) no-repeat top left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:1px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
#steps form fieldset{
    border:none;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
#steps form legend{
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    color:#666;
    font-size:24px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    width:590px;
    padding:5px 0px 5px 10px;
    margin:10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    border-top:1px solid #d9d9d9;
}
#steps form p{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    margin:5px 0px;
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    width:400px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
}
#steps form p label{
    width:160px;
    float:left;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:15px;
    line-height:26px;
    color:#666;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#steps form input:not([type=radio]),
#steps form textarea,
#steps form select{
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
}
#steps form input:focus{
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    background-color:#FFFEEF;
}
#steps form p.submit{
    background:none;
    border:none;
    -moz-box-shadow:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
#steps form button {
 border:none;
 outline:none;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin: 0px auto;
    clear:both;
    padding: 7px 25px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Century Gothic", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    background:#4797ED;
}
#steps form button:hover {
    background:#d8d8d8;
    color:#666;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
    ul{ border:0; margin:0; padding:0; }
 
#pagination-clean li
{
    border:0; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    font-size:11px;
    list-style:none;
}
 
#pagination-clean li, #pagination-clean a
{
    border:solid 1px #DEDEDE
    margin-right:2px;
}
 
#pagination-clean .previous-off, #pagination-clean .next-off 
{
    color:#888888
    display:block;
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:3px 4px;
}
 
#pagination-clean .next a, #pagination-clean .previous a 
{
    font-weight:bold;
    border:solid 1px #FFFFFF;
}
 
#pagination-clean .active
{
    color:#00000
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:4px 6px;
}
 
#pagination-clean a:link, #pagination-clean a:visited 
{
    color:#0033CC
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:3px 6px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
 
#pagination-clean a:hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
p.prev::before {
     content:"";
     position:absolute;left:-25px;top:0;
     
     /* taille */  
     height:0;width:0; 
     
     /* les bordures */
     border-right:36px solid #AAAAAA;
     border-bottom:18px solid transparent;
     border-top:18px solid transparent;
     }
p.prev::after {
     content:"";
     position:absolute;left:-25px;top:0;
     
     /* taille */  
     height:0;width:0; 
     
     /* les bordures */
     border-right:36px solid #AAAAAA;
     border-bottom:18px solid transparent;
     border-top:18px solid transparent;
     }
    
span.reference {
 position: fixed;
 left: 5px;
 top: 5px;
 font-size: 10px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

span.reference a {
 color: #555;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

span.reference a:hover {
 color: #000;
}

h1 {
 color: #ccc;
 font-size: 40px;
 text-shadow: 5px 1px 1px #fff;
 padding: 30px;
}
#slider ul, #slider li
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
}
 
#slider, #slider li
{ 
 width:500px;
 height:200px;
 overflow:hidden; 
}
 
span#prevBtn{}
 
span#nextBtn{}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HPS REGISTER</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="description" content="HPS REGISTER " />
<meta name="keywords"
 content="jquery, form, sliding, usability, css3, validation, javascript" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/style.css" type="text/css"
 media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sliding.form.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" >

</script>

</head>



<body>
 <img class="left" src="img/hps.png" width="150" height="100" alt=""
  title="" style="float: left; margin: 0 180px 0 30px;" />

</body>

<div id="content">

 <h1>HPS REGISTER</h1>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="steps">
   
   <form method="post" action="createbank">


    <fieldset class="step">

     <legend>Account</legend>
     <p>
      <label for="clientname">Client name<span class="requis">*</span></label>
      <input id="clientname" name="clientname" />
     </p>
     <p>
      <label for="email">Email</label> <input id="email" name="email"
       placeholder="info@hps.net" type="email" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
     </p>
     <p>
      <label for="password">Password<span class="requis">*</span></label>
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password"
       AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
     </p>


    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="step">
     <legend>Personal Details</legend>
     <p>
      <label for="name">Full Name</label> <input id="name" name="name"
       type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
     </p>
     <p>
      <label for="country">Country</label> <input id="country"
       name="country" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
     </p>
     <p>
      <label for="phone">Phone</label> <input id="phone" name="phone"
       placeholder="e.g. +212622222222" type="tel" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
     </p>
     <p>
      <label for="website">Website</label> <input id="website"
       name="website"
       placeholder="e.g. http://www.hps.com
        type="
        AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
     </p>
    </fieldset>



    <fieldset class="step">

     <legend>client bank information</legend>
     <p>
      <label for="banktag">Bank tag <span class="requis">*</span></label>
      <input id="banktag" name="banktag" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
     </p>
     <p>
      <label for="currency">Currency<span class="requis">*</span></label>
      <input id="currency" name="currency" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
     </p>
     <p>
      <label for="datesystem">Date system <span class="requis">*</span></label>
      <input id="datesystem" name="datesystem" type="text"
       AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
     </p>
     <p>
      <label for="bankname">Bank name<span class="requis">*</span></label>
      <input id="bankname" name="bankname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />

     </p>
     <p>
      <label for="schemaname">Schema name <span class="requis">*</span>
      </label> <input id="schemaname" name="schemaname" type="text"
       AUTOCOMPLETE=off />

     </p>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset class="step">
     <legend>Confirm</legend>
     <p>IF Everything in the form is correctly filled your
      registration will be made . Otherwise an error message will be
      generate .In this last step the user can confirm the submission of
      the form.</p>

     <p class="submit">
      <button id="registerButton" type="submit">generate</button>

     </p>
                

    </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>

 <div id="result">
  
    <button id="prev">Prev</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
    </div>
            
  <div id="navigation" style="display: none;">

   <ul>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Personal Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bank information</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Confirm</a></li>
   </ul>

  </div>
 </div>



</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do something like this.

```
  $("#next").click(function() {
    var v = $("#navigation ul li.selected");
    var n = $(v).next("li").length;
    if (n == 1){
      v.removeClass("selected").next("li").find("a").trigger("click")
    }
  });


  $("#prev").click(function() {
    var v = $("#navigation ul li.selected");
    var n = $(v).prev("li").length;
    if (n == 1){
      v.removeClass("selected").prev("li").find("a").trigger("click")
    }
  });
```

This will check if there is a next/prev `li` when you click on a `button.

```js
$(function() {
  /*
  number of fieldsets
  */

  var fieldsetCount = $('#formElem').children().length;

  /*
  current position of fieldset / navigation link
  */
  var current = 1;

  /*
  sum and save the widths of each one of the fieldsets
  set the final sum as the total width of the steps element
  */
  var stepsWidth = 0;
  var widths = new Array();
  $('#steps .step').each(function(i) {
    var $step = $(this);
    widths[i] = stepsWidth;
    stepsWidth += $step.width();
  });
  $('#steps').width(stepsWidth);

  /*
  to avoid problems in IE, focus the first input of the form
  */
  $('#formElem').children(':first').find(':input:first').focus();

  /*
  show the navigation bar
  */
  $('#navigation').show();

  /*
  when clicking on a navigation link 
  the form slides to the corresponding fieldset
  */
  $('#navigation a').bind('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var prev = current;
    $this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
    $this.parent().addClass('selected');
    /*
    we store the position of the link
    in the current variable 
    */
    current = $this.parent().index() + 1;
    /*
    animate / slide to the next or to the corresponding
    fieldset. The order of the links in the navigation
    is the order of the fieldsets.
    Also, after sliding, we trigger the focus on the first 
    input element of the new fieldset
    If we clicked on the last link (confirmation), then we validate
    all the fieldsets, otherwise we validate the previous one
    before the form slided
    */
    $('#steps').stop().animate({
      marginLeft: '-' + widths[current - 1] + 'px'
    }, 500, function() {
      if (current == fieldsetCount)
        validateSteps();
      else
        validateStep(prev);
      $('#formElem').children(':nth-child(' + parseInt(current) + ')').find(':input:first').focus();
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  /*
  clicking on the tab (on the last input of each fieldset), makes the form
  slide to the next step
  */
  $('#formElem > fieldset').each(function() {
    var $fieldset = $(this);
    $fieldset.children(':last').find(':input').keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.which == 9) {
        $('#navigation li:nth-child(' + (parseInt(current) + 1) + ') a').click();
        /* force the blur for validation */
        $(this).blur();
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });

  /*
  validates errors on all the fieldsets
  records if the Form has errors in $('#formElem').data()
  */
  function validateSteps() {
    var FormErrors = false;
    for (var i = 1; i < fieldsetCount; ++i) {
      var error = validateStep(i);
      if (error == -1)
        FormErrors = true;
    }
    $('#formElem').data('errors', FormErrors);
  }

  /*
  validates one fieldset
  and returns -1 if errors found, or 1 if not
  */
  function validateStep(step) {
    if (step == fieldsetCount) return;

    var error = 1;
    var hasError = false;
    $('#formElem').children(':nth-child(' + parseInt(step) + ')').find(':input:not(button)').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var valueLength = jQuery.trim($this.val()).length;

      if (valueLength == '') {
        hasError = true;
        $this.css('background-color', '#FFEDEF');
      } else
        $this.css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
    });
    var $link = $('#navigation li:nth-child(' + parseInt(step) + ') a');
    $link.parent().find('.error,.checked').remove();

    var valclass = 'checked';
    if (hasError) {
      error = -1;
      valclass = 'error';
    }
    $('<span class="' + valclass + '"></span>').insertAfter($link);

    return error;
  }

  /*
  if there are errors don't allow the user to submit
  */
  $('#registerButton').bind('click', function() {
    if ($('#formElem').data('errors')) {
      alert('Please correct the errors in the Form');
      return false;
    }
  });

  $("#next").click(function() {
    var v = $("#navigation ul li.selected");
    var n = $(v).next("li").length;
    if (n == 1){
      v.removeClass("selected").next("li").find("a").trigger("click")
    }
  });


  $("#prev").click(function() {
    var v = $("#navigation ul li.selected");
    var n = $(v).prev("li").length;
    if (n == 1){
      v.removeClass("selected").prev("li").find("a").trigger("click")
    }
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  color: #444444;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#content {
  margin: 15px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#steps {
  width: 600px;
  /*height:320px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.step {
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
  /*height:320px;*/
}

#navigation {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

#navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 22px;
}

#navigation ul li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 2px;
}

#navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #777;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.09, rgb(240, 240, 240)), color-stop(0.55, rgb(227, 227, 227)), color-stop(0.78, rgb(240, 240, 240)));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(240, 240, 240) 9%, rgb(227, 227, 227) 55%, rgb(240, 240, 240) 78%)
}

#navigation ul li a:hover,
#navigation ul li. ted a {
  background: #d8d8d8;
  color: #666;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

span.checked {
  background: transparent url(../img/checked.png) no-repeat top left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

span.error {
  background: transparent url(img/error.png) no-repeat top left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#steps form fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#steps form legend {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  width: 590px;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

#steps form p {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
}

#steps form p label {
  width: 160px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 15px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #666;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#steps form input:not([type=radio]),
#steps form textarea,
#steps form select {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#steps form input:focus {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
  background-color: #FFFEEF;
}

#steps form p.submit {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#steps form button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px auto;
  clear: both;
  padding: 7px 25px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
  background: #4797ED;
}

#steps form button:hover {
  background: #d8d8d8;
  color: #666;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  ul {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #pagination-clean li {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    list-style: none;
  }
  #pagination-clean li,
  #pagination-clean a {
    border: solid 1px #DEDEDE margin-right:2px;
  }
  #pagination-clean .previous-off,
  #pagination-clean .next-off {
    color: #888888 display:block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px 4px;
  }
  #pagination-clean .next a,
  #pagination-clean .previous a {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
  }
  #pagination-clean .active {
    color: #00000 font-weight:bold;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 4px 6px;
  }
  #pagination-clean a:link,
  #pagination-clean a:visited {
    color: #0033CC display:block;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  #pagination-clean a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  p.prev::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -25px;
    top: 0;
    /* taille */
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    /* les bordures */
    border-right: 36px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
  }
  p.prev::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -25px;
    top: 0;
    /* taille */
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    /* les bordures */
    border-right: 36px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
  }
  span.reference {
    position: fixed;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  }
  span.reference a {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  span.reference a:hover {
    color: #000;
  }
  h1 {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 5px 1px 1px #fff;
    padding: 30px;
  }
  #slider ul,
  #slider li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  #slider,
  #slider li {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  span#prevBtn {}
  span#nextBtn {}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>HPS REGISTER</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="HPS REGISTER " />
  <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, form, sliding, usability, css3, validation, javascript" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sliding.form.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

</head>



<body>
  <img class="left" src="img/hps.png" width="150" height="100" alt="" title="" style="float: left; margin: 0 180px 0 30px;" />

</body>

<div id="content">

  <h1>HPS REGISTER</h1>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="steps">

      <form method="post" action="createbank">


        <fieldset class="step">

          <legend>Account</legend>
          <p>
            <label for="clientname">Client name<span class="requis">*</span></label>
            <input id="clientname" name="clientname" />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="email">Email</label> <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="info@hps.net" type="email" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="password">Password<span class="requis">*</span></label>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
          </p>


        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="step">
          <legend>Personal Details</legend>
          <p>
            <label for="name">Full Name</label> <input id="name" name="name" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="country">Country</label> <input id="country" name="country" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="phone">Phone</label> <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="e.g. +212622222222" type="tel" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="website">Website</label> <input id="website" name="website" placeholder="e.g. http://www.hps.com
        type=" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
          </p>
        </fieldset>



        <fieldset class="step">

          <legend>client bank information</legend>
          <p>
            <label for="banktag">Bank tag <span class="requis">*</span></label>
            <input id="banktag" name="banktag" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="currency">Currency<span class="requis">*</span></label>
            <input id="currency" name="currency" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="datesystem">Date system <span class="requis">*</span></label>
            <input id="datesystem" name="datesystem" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="bankname">Bank name<span class="requis">*</span></label>
            <input id="bankname" name="bankname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />

          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="schemaname">Schema name <span class="requis">*</span>
      </label> <input id="schemaname" name="schemaname" type="text" AUTOCOMPLETE=off />

          </p>
        </fieldset>


        <fieldset class="step">
          <legend>Confirm</legend>
          <p>IF Everything in the form is correctly filled your registration will be made . Otherwise an error message will be generate .In this last step the user can confirm the submission of the form.</p>

          <p class="submit">
            <button id="registerButton" type="submit">generate</button>

          </p>


        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="result">

      <button id="prev">Prev</button>
      <button id="next">Next</button>
    </div>

    <div id="navigation" style="display: none;">

      <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="#">Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Personal Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bank information</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Confirm</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>



  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @YousraEladib Happy to help, if this solved your problem, you should considder marking this as answer so others know